# Problem with a Markov's Matrix

Tags: markov-chains

I recently discovered the [Markov process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_process).
To simplify my work, I use the following code taken from the [`DiscreteMarkovProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscreteMarkovProcess.html?q=DiscreteMarkovProcess) documentation:

```
K = DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0}, ({
                                       {0, 1/2, 1/2},
                                       {1/2, 0, 1/2},
                                       {1/2, 1/2, 0}
                                     })
                         ];

data = RandomFunction[K, {0, 10}]
```

However, I am facing a case where the code does not seem to work.
In fact, when I use the following matrix `RandomFunction` does not return a result:

```
    {{0.666667, 0.333333, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 
      0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0.0263158, 0., 0.315789, 0.105263, 0.526316, 
      0.0263158, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.655172, 0.344828, 0., 0.,
      0.}, {0., 0., 0.0481928, 0.060241, 0.678715, 0.176707, 0., 0., 
      0.0361446}, {0., 0., 0.210526, 0.105263, 0.684211, 0., 0., 0., 
      0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 
      0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.181818, 0.181818, 0.272727, 
      0.181818, 0.181818}}
```

To investigate the problem I wrote the following code:

```
    TheV = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {4, 4}];
    no = Total /@ TheV;
    TheVno = Table[TheV[[i]]/no[[i]], {i, 1, Length@no, 1}];
    K = DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, TheVno];
    data = RandomFunctionK, {0, 10}]
```

This code seems to show that in some cases `RandomFunction` does not work. What is happening in these cases ? Do I need to replace the command `RandomFunction` with something else ?

*Edit n°1*

---

To better investigate the problem I wrote the following code :

```
MarkovTest[x_, y_] :=
  Block[
        {step1, step2, step31, step311, step32, step322, step4, 
         step41, step5, step51, step6, step61, res},

         step1 = Table[
                       RandomReal[{0, 1}, {BlockRandom[RandomInteger[{1, 18}]], 
                       RandomInteger[{1, 18}]}],
                       {i, 1, x, 1}
                      ];
         step2 = Table[
                       Total /@ step1[[i]],
                       {i, 1, x, 1}
                      ];
         step31 = Table[
                        N[step1[[i, j]]/step2[[i, j]], y],
                        {i, 1, Length@step1,1}, {j, 1, Length@step1[[i]],1}
                       ];
         step311 = Table[
                         Rationalize@(step1[[i, j]]/step2[[i, j]]),
                         {i, 1, Length@step1,1}, {j, 1, Length@step1[[i]],1}
                        ];
         step32 = Table[
                        DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, step31[[i]]],
                        {i, 1, x, 1}
                       ];
         step322 = Table[
                         DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, step311[[i]]],
                         {i, 1, x, 1}
                        ];
         step4 = Table[
                       RandomFunction[step32[[i]], {0, 5}],
                       {i, 1, x, 1}
                      ];
         step41 = Table[
                        RandomFunction[step322[[i]], {0, 5}],
                        {i, 1, x, 1}
                       ];

         step5 = Head /@ step4;
         step51 = Head /@ step41;
         step6 = Count[step5, TemporalData];
         step61 = Count[step51, TemporalData];

         res = {step6, step61}
   ];
```

With this function, you can see the different cases where `RandomFunction` does not work.
As mentioned by ubpdqn the main problem seems to be the arithmetic precision.
I continue to work on the problem.

PS : Obviously, I checked that the given matrix is stochastic....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found a reliable way to always get the results from the command `RandomFunction`.

A stochastic matrix is a real square matrix, with each row summing to 1.
Even if this condition is satisfied, it often happens that the command `RandomFunction` does not work. This is due to how Mathematica manages the arithmetic accuracy of these numbers.

You can see a basic solution through the following code :

```
    l1 = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {BlockRandom[RandomInteger[{10, 15}]], 
        RandomInteger[{10, 15}]}];
    l2 = Total /@ l1;
    l3 = Table[Round[l1[[i]]/l2[[i]], 0.0005], {i, 1, Length@l1, 1}];
    l4 = Map[Rationalize[#] &, l3, {2}];

     Head@(RandomFunction[DiscreteMarkovProcess[1, l4], {0, 5}]) == TemporalData
```

In the previous lines of code, even if Mathematica must make a correction, it still provide `TemporalData`.

To avoid possible problems with matrix in the Markov process, we can use the following function :

```
MarkovGarantee[x_] := Map[Rationalize[Round[#, 0.00005]] &, x, {2}]
```

This solution is empirical. I'm still open to a more elegant solutions.

*Edit n°1*

---

A better solution :

```
MarkovGarantee[x_] :=
  Block[
        {step1, step2, res},

         step1 = Map[Rationalize[Round[#, 0.00005]] &, x, {2}];
         step2 = (1 - Total /@ step1)/Length@x;
         res = Table[step1[[i]] + step2[[i]], {i, 1, Length@step1, 1}]
       ];
```

This solution don't generate any messages of error.

*Edit n°2*

---

A better solution :

```
MarkovGarantee2[x_] :=
  Block[
        {step1, step2, step3, step4, step5, step6, step7},

        step1 = Map[Rationalize[Round[#, 0.00005]] &, x, {2}];
        step2 = (1 - Total /@ step1)/Length@x;
        step3 = step2*(Length@x);
        step4 = Map[Count[#, Except[0]] &, step1];
        step5 = Map[step3[[#]]/step4[[#]] &, Range[1, Length@step3, 1]];
        step6 = Position[#, y_ /; y != 0] & /@ step1;
        step7 =
               Table[
                     MapAt[# + step5[[i]] &, step1[[i]], step6[[i]]],
                     {i, 1, Length@step6, 1}
                    ]
       ];
```

This solution enable to avoid the appearance of negative number.

Answer (score 6):

Apart from rounding errors, which Mathematica normalizes, this does work.

```
mat = {{0.666667, 0.333333, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 
    1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0.0263158, 0., 0.315789, 0.105263, 
    0.526316, 0.0263158, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.655172, 
    0.344828, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.0481928, 0.060241, 0.678715, 
    0.176707, 0., 0., 0.0361446}, {0., 0., 0.210526, 0.105263, 
    0.684211, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.}, {0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 
    0.181818, 0.181818, 0.272727, 0.181818, 0.181818}};
dmk = Quiet@DiscreteMarkovProcess[{1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}, mat];
Graph[dmk]
```

[image]

I leave it up to OP to check whether this is intended process.

Using `RandomFunction`:

```
llp = ListLinePlot[#, 
     InterpolationOrder -> 0] & /@ (RandomFunction[dmk, {0, 20}, 100][
     "Paths"]);
```

The following gif was generated from `llp`:

[image]

Comment: I was rather surprised that in your case the command `RandomFunction` works with my matrix.
However, this confirms that the problem seems to come from the management of the arithmetic precision by Mathematica.

Answer (score 2):

Your random matrix is not a valid transition matrix:

```
mat = {{0.666667, 0.333333, 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0.0263158, 0., 0.315789, 0.105263, 
    0.526316, 0.0263158, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.655172, 0.344828, 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0.0481928, 0.060241, 0.678715, 
    0.176707, 0., 0., 0.0361446}, {0., 0., 0.210526, 0.105263, 0.684211, 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0.,
     0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.}, {0., 0., 0., 0., 0.181818, 0.181818, 0.272727, 0.181818, 0.181818}};

 Total[mat[[All, 1 ;; -1]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can see the probabilities do not add to `1`.

While the first matrix you used which work does:

```
mat = {{0, 1/2, 1/2}, {1/2, 0, 1/2}, {1/2, 1/2, 0}};
Total[mat[[All, 1 ;; -1]]]
(* {1, 1, 1} *)
```

You can't just use any random matrix for `DiscreteMarkovProcess`, the matrix must have certain properties.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix

Comment: The rows should add up to 1, not the columns.

Comment: Which means that your answer is incorrect. I suggest you delete it. I don't understand the upvotes here.